# Apply styles to only to one element

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I am including styles in normal way like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/boostrap.css" type="text/css" />
```

this styles has a lot of styles which destroy my main view, it applies to body element, is it possible to applay the style only to one particular div?

Comment: Now that totally depends on what is in your css file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put that `<div>` into a separate page and include bootstrap CSS only in that page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/boostrap.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>This is your DIV</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Your main page won't be touched by that and you'll be able to display that div inside your main page simply using an `iframe`, change (for example) this:

```
<div>This is your DIV</div>
```

To this:

```
<iframe src="url of the other page"></iframe>
```

Of course you may need to change little bit the logic of your page to accommodate this (primary I guess because of server side C# code, for client side JavaScript code it should be easier because the come from the same domain).

Comment: but then i affact on master page which i don't wanna to

Comment: @kosnkov No, don't put it in the master page. The "other page" is without master page (let's try linking a simple HTML page to see how it works and you'll understand). Of course the link to Bootstrap CSS must be in the "other page" only.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can do that by ID:

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

and then the CSS would be:

```
#myDiv { ... }
```

and that will apply that style to **anything** named `myDiv`. You could also use classes:

```
<div class="someClass"></div>
```

and then the CSS would be:

```
.someClass { ... }
```

and that will apply that style to **anything** with that class attached.

---

Based on what you're describing, surrounding the generality of the CSS that's breaking the already defined CSS, you're going to want to get rid of those general element styles and use ID's because it sounds like you're trying to merge some CSS.

Answer (score -1):

You try to remove all styles of body with javascript code, and after that, after you add a name/id to the body style in your correct css, set this as class attribute of your body. (js code too after the document is completely loaded)

Another (stupid) solution depends on what do you have in the css file. Do you can edit the /css/boostrap.css, simply replace all body word with ".body1" (fe => make a class from it)?